# Select lists from lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an list with x items. I wish to get an results that groups this list based of a number and not a property.

For example.

I have a list of 8 items. I want to group them by 3.
I want to get a List thats contains three lists, where the first two lists contains each three items and the last list the remaining two.

I want a more elegant solution than this:

```
private static List<List<string>> GroupBy(List<string> pages, int groupSize)
{
    var result = new List<List<TrimlinePage>>();
    while (!(result.Count != 0 && result.Last().Count % 3 > 0))
    {
        int skip = result.Count*groupSize;
        var group = pages.Skip(skip).Take(groupSize).ToList();
        result.Add(group);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the integer divison  trick:

```
List<List<string>> lists = pages
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index }) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / groupSize)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Example:

```
int groupSize = 3;
var pages = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
List<List<string>> lists = pages
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / groupSize)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
foreach(var list in lists)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));
```

Output:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G
```

So this approach will give you lists with the specified max-size, in this case 3. If you instead want to ensure that you always get three lists you need to use `%` instead of `/`:

```
List<List<string>> lists = pages
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index }) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.index % groupSize)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,100);
var query = list
              .Select((x, i) => new {x, i})
              .GroupBy(v => v.i / 3).Select(g => g.Select(v =>v.x.ToList()))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using side effects (which is generally discouraged):

```
private static List<List<string>> GroupBy(List<string> pages, int groupSize)
{
    var i = 0;
    return pages.GroupBy(p => i++ / 3, (k, g) => g.ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Or if you want to avoid relying on side effects, you could use this:

```
private static List<List<string>> GroupBy(List<string> pages, int groupSize)
{
    return pages.Select(p => new { p, i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.i / 3)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.p).ToList())
                .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not the best solution. Often good old indexing is much more readable and efficient.

```
private static List<List<T>> GroupBy(List<T> pages, int groupSize)
{
    var result = new List<List<T>>();
    List<T> l;
    for (int i=0; i < pages.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i%groupSize == 0)
        {
            l = new List<T>();
            result.Add(l);
        }
        l.Add(pages[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) which contains the [Partition](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Partition.cs) method.

It's available via NuGet.